# PHP PDO Correct use of JOINS for mySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, join, pdo

How would one correctly use a JOIN to add each row that matches the ID from a second table in as a column header of the first table.

Example.

**THEME TABLE**

```
ID     TITLE    DATE    TEXT
1     logo     23101    some sample text
2     back     23101    some sample text
```

**THEME_META** Table

```
refID     field     value
1         width     300
1         height    190
1         alt       some alternate text
2         bgcolor   #222
```

MySQL query would then be `SELECT * FROM theme WHERE date = ?`

I would then have foreached my results and have my theme item in a variable which I can use to echo the value for any column in the row.

eg. `echo $theme['title'];`

How would I also be able via a JOIN to be able to echo

```
$theme['width'] . $theme['height'] . $theme['alt']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is *pivot* the column `field` in the `theme_meta` table for each `refID`, unfortunatly, MySQL doesn't have the pivot table operator, but you can use the `CASE` expression to do so:

```
SELECT
  t.id,
  t.date,
  t.text,
  MAX(CASE WHEN m.field = 'width' THEN m.value ELSE NULL END) AS Width,
  MAX(CASE WHEN m.field = 'height' THEN m.value ELSE NULL END) AS height,
  MAX(CASE WHEN m.field = 'alt' THEN m.value ELSE NULL END) AS alt, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN m.field = 'bgcolor' THEN m.value ELSE NULL END) AS bgcolor,
FROM theme AS t
INNER JOIN theme_meta AS m ON t.id = m.refID
GROUP BY t.id,
  t.date,
  t.text;
```

---

**Update:** To do this dynamically instead of listing the values manually, you have to use dynamic sql, like this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(IF(m.field  = ''',
      m.field, ''', m.value, NULL)) AS ', '''', m.field  , '''')
  ) INTO @sql
FROM theme_meta AS m;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT t.id,t.date,t.text, ', 
                  @sql , '
    FROM theme AS t
INNER JOIN theme_meta AS m ON t.id = m.refID
GROUP BY t.id,
  t.date,
  t.text;');

prepare stmt 
FROM @sql;

execute stmt;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b611b/5)

Comment: Very clever, but it assumes we know what the fields are we are looking for. Since I intend to deploy this query for any theme element we may not know what the fields are called. Is there a way to match the ID then take the value of one column in the row as the new column name and another a column as its value?

Comment: @RobinKnight - Yes, in this case you have to use dynamic sql, I will update my answer, give some minutes please.

Comment: @MahmoudGarnal, exceptional. 2 more questions. 1 Assuming we have a theme_meta table full of hundreds of different field names for various different matching themes would this still be quicker than using a separate mySQL query for each one, and secondly would this work as a mySQL query in PHP PDO. THanks

Comment: @RobinKnight - I think this will be faster, this will do a few calls to the database, instead of a call for each value. For PHP PDO, I think no it won't work, you have to put it inside a stored procedure and call that procedure instead.